# AWS Load Balancing all of same websocket route to the same instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm writing an application where multiple users connect to a websocket server with the following url as an example `wss://example.com/ws/1234`.
Multiple users may connect to the same one and I require them to all connect to the same ec2 instance. All that try to connect to `wss://example.com/ws/1234` will go to the same server, and all users that connect to `wss://example.com/ws/4325` will also go to the same server. These routes are generated dynamically.
If a client is the first client to connect to an endpoint, it will route them to the server with the least CPU load. If a client is connecting to an endpoint that has already been connected to, they will be sent to the same server.

I've tried going into the listener rules for my ec2 auto-scaling group. But, I couldn't find any settings that seemed like they would do the trick.

My attempt:
[image: Attempt]

Comment: can you explain once again, what are you trying to achieve and what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Essentially, I want the first client to connect to a route (wss://example.com/<route>) to be routed in a default manner (to the instance with the lowest cpu load). But when an instance is connected to with a new route for the first time, I want it to receive all subsequent connections to the same route.